# How to return specific row from database that include image path

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I write below code that correctly returns an image that its path stored in the database.

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public IActionResult RetrieveFile(int id)
{
    string pathImage = "";

    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    string query = @"select image from mydb.courses where id=@id";

    string sqlDataSource = _configuration.GetConnectionString("UsersAppCon");
    MySqlDataReader myReader;

    using (MySqlConnection mycon = new MySqlConnection(sqlDataSource))
    {
        mycon.Open();

        using (MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand(query, mycon))
        {
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
            pathImage = (string)myCommand.ExecuteScalar();
            mycon.Close();
        }
    }

    var path = @$"{pathImage}";
    var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
    return File(fs, "image/jpeg");
}
```

Furthermore, I want to return the `id`, `price`, and `name` with the image from the database and send it to the client.

[image]

What changes should I make to the above code to send me What I want?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use ExecuteScalar, but you need to call ExecuteReader to get back an MySqlDataReader and then get the single inputs from the reader fields. and of course, you should change the query to get the required fields

```
string query = @"select id,price,name,image from mydb.courses where id=@id";
string sqlDataSource = _configuration.GetConnectionString("UsersAppCon");
using (MySqlConnection mycon = new MySqlConnection(sqlDataSource))
{
    mycon.Open();
    using (MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand(query, mycon))
    {
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
        // Then you use the reader to get the single field values
        using(MySqlDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader())
        {
            // Always check if the where clause produces records to read
            if(myReader.Read())
            {
                // I have assumed the datatype for the fields. Change GetXXXX if different
                pathImage = myReader.GetString("image");
                id = myReader.GetInt32("id");
                price = myReader.GetDecimal("price");
                name = myReader.GetString("name");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that you don't need to close the connection when it is declared inside a using statement. Also it is better to not use AddWithValue albeit in case of integers its problems are not relevant and MySql seems to be a bit more resilient than other db

Comment: Hi @Steve, Thanks for your answer. Now, How do I return pathImage, id, price, and name values to the client?

Comment: They are separate variables now. I suggest you to create a class with properties to support these 4 values. Create an instance of this class and set the properties with the values returned by the datareader. Now you just return the class instance to the calling code